# Xamarin Forms Display image from Embedded resource using XAML

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to display and embedded image in a shared project resource (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin) on microsoft documentation).

I created the ImageResourceExtension, the project compiles, but I get the following error when I start the project :

> Could not load type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IReferenceProvider' from
>   assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0

Here's my code :

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>

        <Image x:Name="imgTest" Source="{local:ImageResource img.jpg}" />

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

EmbeddedImage.cs

```
namespace App1
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Source))]
    public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null)
                return null;

            // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source, typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            return imageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your code? Are you sure the problem is related to the image?

Comment: If I remove the <Image /> I do not get the error.  So pretty sure its related :)  I added the code to my initial post.  Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the path of your image? Where is your picture saved in your shared-project?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this, it works for me

xyz.xaml.cs

```
imgName.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("ProjectName.Images.backicon.png");
```

xyz.xaml

```
<Image x:Name="imgName" />
```

Hope this code helps you!!

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<Image x:Name="imgTest" Source="{local:ImageResource img.jpg}" />
```

With:

```
<Image x:Name="imgTest" Source="{local:ImageResource 'Project.Folder.img.jpg'}" />
```

And Replace:

```
var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source, typeof(...));
```

With:

```
var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing if the answer is still valid for you, but I usually have an Assets folder outside my solution which contains Android specific folders (drawables), iOS specific folders (Resource with @2x and @3x) and a Common folder for shared images.

In my solution I **add these files as a link** in the folders they should be associated with. On Android in the Resources/Drawable and iOS in the Resource. In this case Common files can be shared across both platforms without physically copying them.

As a bonus, updates to these Assets can be overwritten in the folder outside my solution and will be used within my solution without any additional action to be taken.

Answer (score -1):

If you add the Image to your Android drawable folder, or to the iOS Resource folder, you don't need any extension. You can simply do:

```
 <Image x:Name="imgTest" Source="img.jpg" />
```

Comment: I know that.  The point is that I want to share the resource across projects.  Not to copy the files on each project (I find that pretty annoying)

Comment: Not an answer to the post.